# Ruby on Rails image_tag not displaying the image Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Im trying to get a profile picture to display for users to with no luck.  Ive installed the `carrierwave` gem in the gemfile along with `mini_magick`.

Image uploader

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
  end

  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

show.html.erb

```
...

<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) if @user.avatar?%>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user)%>
```

controller (the alart is being displayed, instead of the image)

```
def update 
        if @user.update(user_params)
            redirect_to @user 
        else 
            flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
            render :edit 
        end
    end

    private 

    def check_authorization
        unless current_user.id == params[:id].to_i
            redirect_to root_url 
        end 
    end

    def set_user 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params 
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :avatar)
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow what a great community we have here! So helpful! Actually I had to go to reddit to get the damn answer. Im sure there will be people in the future that will have the same issue I had and will unfortunately look to this site first for an answer. What worked for me was installing `imagemagick` If you're using a Mac, and have homebrew installed its as simple has `brew install imagemagick`. Restart you server and it should work.